Interactive plots with Sagemath outside Jupyter
I'm not very familiar with Sagemath. I would like a simple interactive plot, of the sort
@interact
def plt(k=1):
  show(plot(some_function(k, ...)))

In Jupyter these work fine, but I'd like a solution that does not rely on Jupyter, only my own shell. In Matplotlib you have the option to view plots in a Qt application with interactive controls and stuff like that, whereas with Sage, my plot only seems to open in the default PNG viewer.
Thanks in advance.
